# invoking iphone address book within another application?

Tags: iphone

In my app i need to invoke the address book as part my app, that means i should not quit my app, within my app
i need to launch the native address book of the iphone, is it possible by any means?

Answer (score 2):

[Read the Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone)